# Reading a table in PDF Itextsharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I was trying to read a PDF using Itextsharp in .NET application. I am able to read individual word sccessfully .  The challenge I am facing now is reading a table. I have a table structure like this:

[image]

Please note that here some of  column names  are two-lined. for example Department Code and Employee Identification Number.

So my requirement is to read the Employee Identification number and salary if the employee belongs to 'HR' department. For this I have to check whether a column named 'Department Code' exists in the PDF file.

When I  read this table using iTextsharp, what happens is let us say 'Department' part of 'Department Code' column comes at poition  1 , but the 'Code' comes 5th position.This is because this column is displayed in two lines and there are other four words exists in the pdf before I read the 'Code'part of this column. I am totally stuck at this :(

Anybody has any idea how to make sure that a column name 'Department Code' exists and read corresponding values from this table.

Appreciate your help!

Regards,
Jaleel

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PDFs don't actually have a concept of "tables". What looks like a table is just a bunch of arbitrary text that happens to have lines around it. Most PDF creation libraries allow you to create content from a "table" but ultimately those turn them into text and unrelated lines. Also, what you see as a "blank cell" is probably actually no text at all (although it could be a space).

For this kind of thing you're pretty much just going to have to come up with some arbitrary rules specific to your document. You *could* try to calculate where lines exist relative to text and try to rebuild your table in a more logical format but you're going to be hard-pressed to do that.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the help! I am trying to find those arbitrary rules :)